# How to join two list of tuples without duplicates

Tags: python, list, tuples, sql-server-express

I am running two queries to a database, the result i get from each, is a list of tuples which is perfect. I would like to join these into one list of tuples. These are examples of the tuples:

```
list1 = [('abc', 1 ),  ('def', 2) ... ]
list2 = [(1000, 'abc'),  (2000, 'def' ), (3000, 'def') ... ]
```

I want to create just one list of tuples and i join them like this:

```
q = []
for i in list1:
            for j in list2:         
                if i[0] == (j[1]):
                    i = i + (j[0],)
                    q.append(i)
```

This returns duplicates in my new list `q` as i get something like this:

```
q = [('abc', 1 , 1000) , ('def', 2, 2000), ('def', 2, 2000, 3000) ...]
```

How can I avoid getting duplicates like the second list of tuples in the q list? 
I want just `('def', 2, 2000, 3000)` and not this `('def', 2, 2000), ('def', 2, 2000, 3000)`

I've been stuck on this for a while so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Using nested loops for this is not a good idea if the lists are large. See below for further details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using nested loops is ok if your lists are fairly small but it soon becomes inefficient for larger lists. Eg, if len(list1) == 10 and len(list2) == 20 the code inside the inner loop is executed 200 times.

Here's an algorithm that builds the desired list of tuples via a dictionary. The dictionary stores the tuple data in lists because it's more efficient: it's possible to append to lists, whereas tuples are immutable, so each time you add an item to the end of a tuple with `i = i + (j[0],)` you're actually creating a new tuple object (as well as the temporary `(j[0],)` tuple) and discarding the old one that was bound to `i`.

```
list1 = [('abc', 1 ), ('def', 2), ('ghi', 3)]
list2 = [
    (1000, 'abc'),
    (2000, 'def'),
    (2100, 'def'),
    (3000, 'ghi'),
    (3100, 'ghi'),
    (3200, 'ghi'),
] 

# Insert list1 data into a dict of lists
d = {t[0]:list(t) for t in list1}

# Append list2 data to the correct list
for v, k in list2:
    d[k].append(v)

# Convert lists back into tuples, using the key order from list1
result = [tuple(d[k]) for k, _ in list1]
for t in result:
    print(t)
```

**output**

```
('abc', 1, 1000)
('def', 2, 2000, 2100)
('ghi', 3, 3000, 3100, 3200)
```

With this algorithm, if len(list1) == 10 and len(list2) == 20 then we have a loop of length 10 to build the dictionary `d`, a loop of length 20 to append the list2 data to `d`'s lists, and another loop of length 10 to build the final list of tuples. he steps inside each of those loops are fairly basic, roughly on par with your `i = i + (j[0],)`, and obviously 40 steps is a lot better than 200. And of course if the input lists had 1000 items each then my code would take 3000 loops in contrast to the one million loops required with the nested loop approach.

I should also mention that this code will raise `KeyError` if `list2` contains a key that's not in `list1`. Presumably this isn't an issue for the data you're processing, since your code (and Sevanteri's) silently ignores such keys. If you *do* need to handle such keys it's fairly simple to do so, but it makes my `list2` loop simpler & more efficient if it doesn't have to handle missing keys.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Right now the list size is only ~20 but in the future it will grow, This is a better long term option

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to append `i` inside the inner loop. Just once at the end of the outer loop.

```
q = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i[0] == j[1]:
            i = i + (j[0],)
    q.append(i)
```

There was also a typo in the outer loop. It should be `list1` instead of just `list`.

Comment: You can remove paren around `(j[1])`. It's not a tuple but a simple value.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Ah, true. Didn't even notice that one. :D

Comment: This, while fine for a toy example, is a terrible example of how to do this. PM 2Ring's is much better.

Comment: @RobertGrant yea I just took the code from the question and fixed. Didn't put that much thought into it.